# Close collaborator stalling progress for territory, how to help company understand?

Tags: politics

I am the only employee of my US company for my territory.
My only collaborator is a consultant salesperson. 
I do not report to him, it's only support as needed.
He spends a lot of time with a few high-forecast US accounts.

As a result:

1. He overlooks the territory, 90-95% of his time goes to the US
2. With nobody else to help, it falls to me to run this "little shop", and when I directly help create new opportunities, he will try stall progress until he can directly talk to the customer. This includes creating conflicting meetings, "competing" with me in conversations with customer, lying to customers about my geographic location or role when relevant, leaving me out of important conversations, etc.

I was able to bring two high-revenue customers onboard, and this person will get the commission. His ideal situation is me helping him out, but without any career advancement: he will not allow me to get prominence or credit for my work.

He also tried replacing me with a non-technical friend, but failed because of the technical gap.

Because of his behaviour, the company cannot really grow outside his "big accounts".

How can I help the company understand the situation?

Comment: Ask permission to work the small accounts you bring in alone.

Comment: This mostly seems like something you need to discuss with your manager, ideally with proposals about how to fix it and proof of his wrong-doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would be interesting to know what is your location, ballpark.

But generally, when you feel under pressure in the role you want / need to fill,
its could be a good idea to talk to the direct supervisor / regional lead someone that is in your chain of responsibility, but not under that salesperson.

You would need proof to support your argument of salesperson sabotage / incompetence and his personal  attacks on you.

Perhaps you can get some sales / customer outreach duties that you need to keep the shop and get the credit / commission you deserve.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the statement to document the issue and report it to management.

In addition, some social engineering on your part might help you out, from the standpoint of prevention.  Are you required to coordinate with this person on every opportunity?  If not, don't tell them about the sales opportunities or your plans for action on those accounts.  They cannot sabotage any opportunity or action that they do not know exists.

Also, don't be afraid to take full ownership of a project, if you can.  Do not rely on this person for assistance, because it seems like instead of getting help, you have to take additional time to perform damage control.  Take over full responsibility for the project.  If that means that you have to learn new skills, then do so.  In the long run, you will get full credit for your work.  And do not ask for permission to take ownership of the project.  Just do it.

You mention that he is not your supervisor.  Perhaps you can make the direct communications to the client and report the results to management.  Try to bypass this guy, if you can.

Good luck!